# save specific directory into the variable and assign it

Tags: php, joomla, include, directory

In my site database configuration file is here

```
/home/itstec2/public_html/pard_config/class/Config.php
```

SO,I'm including it for other files in different folders like bellow after adding **DIR** magic method.it;s also working fine.but,

```
include(__DIR__ . '/../pard_config/class/Config.php');
```

As you can see it is also ugly.Is there anyway to  get this path into a varible and assing into the include like this

```
/home/itstec2/public_html/pard_config/class/Config.php  ==>> to variable

include($getPath.'mod_hello_world2');
```

I see in joomla there is a system like bellow

```
<?php

// include the helper file
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php');

// include the template for display
require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_hello_world2'));
?>
```

Comment: Dou you really need absolute path in include?

Comment: @Ockonal no it's ok whatever

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$getPath = JUri::root() . "pard_config/class/Config.php";
include($getPath.'mod_hello_world2');
```

You have to be careful with including php files in Joomla as sometimes it isn't allowed due to security issues and could come up with a "**Restricted Access**" error

Hope this helps

Comment: What? i need a structure for my site not for jomla

Comment: sorry, I thought you were referring to Joomla as you included the Joomla tag in your question